# Perform rsync while following sym links

Tags: linux, rsync, files, symbolic-link

I have a directory that contains symbolic links to other directories located on different media on my system:

```
/opt/lun1/2011
/opt/lun1/2010
/opt/lun2/2009
/opt/lun2/2008
/opt/lun3/2007
```

But the symbolic links show up as:

```
/files/2011
/files/2010
/files/2009
/files/2008
/files/2007
```

How can I perform an `rsync` that follows the symbolic links?

e.g.:

`rsync -XXX /files/ user@server:/files/`

Answer (score 140, accepted):

The `-L` flag to rsync will sync the contents of files or directories linked to, rather than the symbolic link.

Comment: When I do this, all the receiver symbolic links get deleted and my sender starts re-sending the files.

Comment: Isn't that what you want?  I thought you wanted to have the real files on the receiving side, not just the symlinks.  Do you mean you want the symlinks copied as symlinks, but automagically rewritten to point to the "right" place on the receiving system?  If so, that's not what is normally meant by "an rsync that follows the symbolic links".

Comment: It actually deletes the symbolic links and replaces them with the files.  I want to follow the symbolic links through as if they were regular directories.

Comment: Are these symbolic links to files, or to directories; your comment above suggests both?  Could you paste an example of what you've got on the source side and what you would like to see on the destination side, in the original question?  And by example, I mean some detail: `ls -al` output from the source side.

Comment: Hi -- these are directories.  I got this to work with the -K flag.

Comment: I'm sure SO is making me more stupid..

Comment: To clarify, `-LK` if you want to follow both symlinked files and directories

Comment: Imagine if rsync also had tar options.

Comment: Always be careful when following such suggestions. Test, test, and test before your carry out product run! *`-L` itself will remove all symlinks on your receiver side!*

Comment: Just to tack on to this, I tested with my usual -avP and it looks like the -L needs to prepend my -a to copy the files and not the link itself, so -LavP for my purposes.

Answer (score 34):

You need **both** `-L` and `-K` if you have symlinks on both sides, e.g. you already had your 1st rsync done and want to update the backup using rsync.

```
    -L, --copy-links            transform symlink into referent file/dir
    -K, --keep-dirlinks         treat symlinked dir on receiver as dir
```

In such cases, if you use only `-L`, the symlinks on the receiver side will be wiped out and new real dir will be made.

Comment: This should have been the selected answer.

Answer (score 22):

Just ran into this problem. And if you want rsync to treat symlinked directories as directories, you want the `K` option

`rsync -K /files/ user@server:/files/`

Comment: You might also want to add the --copy-unsafe-links option